# e-commerce with product codes and invoicing

Tags: php, mysql, product, invoice

I know there are probably some scripts out there and I'm sure that I'm overlooking them, but I'm wondering if anyone can point me to a better script or a way to show me how to make one.

What I'm looking for is, an e-commerce type of script that will allow me to put product code in and it will tell the unit price for example say, I am going to sell a product and I go to generate an invoice where I would then put a product number (`e.g. 0001`), it would then display what the product is and total price for the product where I can then print them off or allow the client to login to their own account to view the invoice for payment.

I'm not looking for anything fancy, just a simple system to use and let me to add more product codes if needed.

In theory, here's how I would want it to read:

```
Product Code~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Item~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Price  
0001~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Something Cool~~~~~~~~~50.00  
0002~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~install Something Cool~~~~~~5.00  
Total:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~55.00
```

I hope this makes sense in what I'm looking for and someone could point me into the right direction on were to look.

Comment: It's just a case of databasing your products then calling them thorough a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box Billing will probably do for your level of needs. It supports multiple products and user logs as well as invoicing, etc... It's probably the most simple billing system you'll find for your needs:

URL: http://www.boxbilling.com/

It's free and open source based on PHP & MySQL.

Comment: Thank you i will try that couldnt hurt :)